# How do I create a constructor function in R?

Tags: r, methods

I am attempting to create a constructor function for an object using the S3 00 system in R.

**The arguments of the function should only be r where r is a k × 1 vector that contains the radial measurements of fungi.**

**The constructor function should return an object that is a vector corresponding to r with class equal to growth.**

Here is some data,

```
"theta","r"
0,4
0.31,2.07
0.63,2.15
0.94,3.08
1.26,4.09
1.57,2.39
1.88,1.96
2.2,3.72
2.51,4.72
2.83,2.87
3.14,1.67
3.46,3.51
3.77,4.37
4.08,2.24
4.4,2.23
4.71,4.18
5.03,3.12
5.34,2.67
5.65,2.19
5.97,3.16
```

So I assume the function starts similar to the following?

```
growth <- function(x) {
r <- as.vector(x)
class(r) <- "growth"
r
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. You are taking values for x and then discarding them but leaving in the timing data which above you said should _not_ be included????

Comment: @42- I think I put too much information, and I agree it is very confusing. So now I've edited the post, and I'm just looking for help with, "The arguments of the function should only be r where r is a k × 1 vector that contains the radial measurements of fungi."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One defines a set of functions that operate on a particular S3-class of objects defined by a 'class' attribute. If you want to make a constructor function, you might also want to provide an `as`-method to coerce objects that are not kx1 vectors. The constructor should do some validity checking. In your case where you anticipate giving this constructor an k x 1 vector, you would probably not require k as an argument unless you wanted to shorten the argument to a lesser length than that of the x-argument. So I would suggest putting in a default value of NA which will allow it to be absent unless needed.

If you are going to put this set of functions in a package you will need to read up on those requirements, as well.

```
growth <- function(x,k=NA){ 
    if( length(x) < 2 || (!is.na(k) && k < 2 ) ){ error("insufficient data") }
      # probably want to put in other validity checks
    class(x) <- "growth"
    if (!is.na(k) ){                   
    return(x[1:k])} else{ return(x) }
     }
```

I don't remember if you originally put in the physical rationale for this construction, but I now think I understand what is being done. You are measuring "radial" growth along equally spaced angled lines. Does make me wonder it you might want to later build time-series of such measurements. If you do you might want to look at the well-developed 'zoo'-library. It would allow a K-column (for spatial orientation) by Z-row (for time) objects.

Comment: I actually get an error, " Error in if (length(x) < 2 || !is.na(k) && k < 2 || length(x) < k) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: My effort at putting multiple validity check in one step was misguided.